# Terminal Connecting to Linux Server on OS X

Tags: linux, terminal, server

I'm not entirely sure that I can provide enough information to get the help I need, but I'm trying to connect to a Linux server for my class.

I had my first session today for a class called Multi-User Operating Systems, and we used Macs running Windows.  We used PuTTY and all we had to do was enter the host name, our school usernames and logins to get to our server.  My professor said it was possible to access it via Mac, but has the deepest accent I've heard in my school, making it very hard to understand.  I did a few google searches to figure it out, but nothing seems to be working.  I've sent him an email, but posting here to hopefully get a faster reply as professors are notorious for slow replies.  Thanks for any help.

I'm extremely new to this subject, so please forgive my lack of understanding.

I know of the host address, but since I'm not that great in this subject, I'm not sure if its ethical or not to share.

*UPDATE: Here's some new info, I'm able to connect to the schools server, on a Mac and through terminal, while on a campus Macintosh.  I get right in the first try.  But not on my personal Mac.  Not only does my personal Mac not work at home on my wifi, but it doesn't connect while at school on their network either.  Strange.  Not sure if this information helps anyone or not, but I figure'd I'd include it.

Comment: It's very odd, I've tried about 100 different times and actually fully connected once, got most of my homework done, then was forced to quit when something went haywire.  99 percent of the time, I get "connection closed by remote host" or similar messages when using the exact same line that worked the one time.  Other times, I'll finally get past the first step and get asked for a password and it claims it's not the correct password even though I know it is.  Very irritating to have made it in once tonight and after a hundred attempts and am back to being locked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to ssh on your mac open up the terminal and input the following:

```
ssh yourSchoolUsername@thehost
```

and press enter.

Now you will be prompted for a password, use your school account password to login.

Comment: This works on a school Mac using terminal, but not my personal Macbook Air.  It doesn't work on my Macbook Air at my home on my personal wifi or on the schools wifi.  Wonder why they aren't letting my computer in, all PCs and Macs at school work, and PCs away from school work, but not Macs away from school, at least not my mac.  Could there be a setting on my Macbook Air that isn't correct, causing the connection to fail?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can. You would use the mac terminal and ssh command.

for example:

```
ssh user@domainNameOrIpAddress
```

And then it will prompt you for a password.

[A good tutorial in my opinion.](http://www.ehow.com/how_5088544_use-ssh-mac-os-x.html)

Comment: I think this is what I tried previously with no avail, but I believe the issue lies in me not having enough information on the server.  I just have a host name, but no IP Address.

Comment: What about a port? The default is 22 but if they changed it you can use the -p argument. For example: ssh user@hostname -p 1006

Comment: I'm unsure, I'll be honest, I'm very very foreign to this realm in computer science.  The only information we got was the host, but maybe I'm wrong.  Would it be improper to post the host address to make sure I'm even identifying it correctly?  Maybe that would help, but I'm not sure if it's ok to post that sort of stuff or is it supposed to be kept secret?

Comment: Depends on the server I guess. But no sorry I don't have a test server you can connect to. Also some servers require a public/private key.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to imply I needed a server to test on, I just wasn't sure if it was ethical that I post the host name of my schools server in order to get better help.